# Most frequent byte in file. Java

Tags: java, byte

Task:
Enter a file name from the console. Find the byte or bytes with the maximum number of repetitions. Display them on the screen, separated by spaces. Close the IO stream.

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    String filename = reader.readLine ();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream (filename);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<> ();
    while (fileInputStream.available () > 0) {
        int temp = fileInputStream.read ();
        list.add (temp);

    }
    fileInputStream.close ();
}
```

}

What should i do? can you give me some advice?

Comment: Think about creating a counter for each byte value (bytes can range in value from 0 to 255) then incrementing the proper counter for each byte read.  So for instance if you read a byte whose value was 32 you would increment the counter for value 32 by one.   Do for each byte in the file then sort the counters by count and print.  You could store all the counters in an 256 element array of Integers or in a map of some sort.

Comment: What is your error? Why should we help you with your homework if you make it difficult for us?